# Parse Json array init single object in Spring boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

All I need some help to parse the object on the class base.
I have a list of Imp object. i don't want it map all to the class and create the all object. **I need only the First object of the Imp** in my RtbRequest class.

**Reason:-** why i need to do like that. In imp json **user** send the non-number of imp object's in list and required on one object. i'd want to parse all. Is this possible

My Pojo Class

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RtbRequest {

   // number of attribute
    private Imp imp;

    public void setImp(Imp imp) {
        this.imp = imp;
    }

}
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Imp {

   // number of attribute
   @JsonIgnore
   private Map<String, String> impMap = new HashMap<>();
   private String id;
   private Double bidfloor;
    //final-map
    public void setId(String id) {
        log.info("set--id--rtb--Imp");
        this.id = id;
        impMap.put("impid", getId());
    }


}
```

My Json Object

```
{
    "id": "ded06290-f586-45c6-bbcb-015adba03e39",
    "imp": [{
            "id": "1",
            "video": {
                "linearity": 1,
                "maxduration": 120,
                "protocols": [2, 5, 3, 6],
                "w": 1280,
                "h": 720,
                "startdelay": 0,
                "skip": 1,
                "sequence": 1,
                "playbackmethod": [1, 2, 3],
                "api": [2]
            },
            "bidfloor": 0.0,
            "secure": 1

        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "video": {
                "linearity": 1,
                "maxduration": 120,
                "protocols": [2, 5, 3, 6],
                "w": 1280,
                "h": 720,
                "startdelay": 0,
                "skip": 1,
                "sequence": 1,
                "playbackmethod": [1, 2, 3],
                "api": [2]
            },
            "bidfloor": 0.0,
            "secure": 1
        }
    ]

}
```

My RestController

```
@RequestMapping(value= { "/request/{partner}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, String> getRtbResponse(@PathVariable String partner, @RequestBody RtbRequest request) {}
```

Comment: Why don't you do something like `request.getImps().stream.findFirst().orElse(null)` and retrieve the first element from the list?

Comment: Question still same their. I accept your line's of code work for me. but i'm trying to save my execution time and memory. in your case it first init the all object's after that i used get first object from stream. but suppose that i have 10,000 and many more object in the list it first init all then getting first one it take to much time and memory. while the response send in 0ms.

Comment: really have no idea how much object user send in the list and only need the first one. think how much time i will be take

Comment: The question is, will it save execution time? Jackson probably has to parse the entire JSON anyways to make sure that everything is correct. You're making it difficult for yourself by sending a different request than you expect. Why don't you send the correct request if you don't need all of it?

Comment: Are you saying that the requester sends many JSON objects, but you only MUST only read the first object ? Sounds like a strange requirement, can't you ask him to just send one object?

Comment: I accept it's wrong and I accept it's difficult i'm making but not for the whole application only for the first step of the project. In imp object have 10 attribute of difference class each class have 50 to 150 attribute. user say client send different number of of object's on the base of bidding and I only need the first object of the list to process the data into map.

Comment: and in each attribute of class i'm init the value of attribute in hash-map on the setter method. list is base on RTB standard so he want to break the standard list of object and get the one object from the list

Comment: check json if you send the email will share you

Answer (score 0):

JSON serialization works best if you serialize into strong types, so each JSON object will normally map directly to a Java class. If all your items look like:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "exp": 3600,
    "secure": 0,
    "instl": 1
}
```

you should create an identical Java class, with getters and setters

```
Class Item {
    String id;
    long exp;
    int secure;
    int instl;
    // setters and getter
}
```

The controller method signature should be:

```
 @RequestMapping(value= { "/request/{partner}"}, method = 
 RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, String> getRtbResponse(@RequestBody List<Item> data, @PathVariable String partner) {}
```

If each partner sends in data in different formats, the solution may depend on weather you need to process the data, or simply store it.
If you 'just' need to store the data and not process it, you can use the fact that all JSON object can be handled as maps, so it is possible to make your controller like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value= { "/request/{partner}"}, method = 
 RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, String>> getRtbResponse(@RequestBody List<Map<String, Object>> data, @PathVariable String partner) {}
```

However if you need to process the data in any way, using `Map<String, Object>` is generally not a good plan.

In Java we could create an `Interface PartnerItem` and multiple subclasses, each matching the data submitted by each partner. This is also possible in JSON, but since JSON objects have no name, it needs to be included in some other way. Here is a link to a guide that explains [how Jackson inheritance works](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)

**Note**: Personally I never use array as my top level JSON structure when I design APIs, I always use object. The reason is that I can add additional fields to an object, which allows me to mutate the API in a backwards compatible way - this is not possible if your top-level structure is an array.

Comment: I know the json Structure format start always from the object i only share the list part of the object i update pls check. and the for map, i'm not doing like that

Comment: If the JSON format is not well known you can't map it to a Java class, and you will have to use `Map` for deserialization. If you only want to read the first object you can't use `@RequestBody`. Instead you will have to read int request's InputStream and use a SAX like stream-based parsing. http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api

Comment: hmm. sound good in that case lot of code will be add costume parse data step by step. i like this one but problem is i implement all client requirement. i first imp by used of array at that time i fully handle all the object and other process by getting the first object of imp like that 
 `this.imp.get(0).getVideo()`   and i also replay not possible to handle that why but he say try to do like that. well thanks for help. will try

Answer (score 0):

All Sorry for late replay for this issue i handle this by use of Cross filter.
I first update my **IMP** list to **Object** after that i update the **ReadHttpServletRequest** stream by adding this Request into do-filer change.

**Main Key Point**

> Note:-  final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream =
>                   new ByteArrayInputStream(getNewRequest().getBytes());

```
@Component
public class Cross implements Filter {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Cross.class);

    //********************************
    //           Filter Config      //
    //********************************
    private static Integer count = 0;
    private Long before;


    @Autowired
    ValidatorService validatorService;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {

            // response
            log.info("=================Request-Start-"+(count++)+"-=====================");
            before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ReadHttpServletRequest requestWrapper = new ReadHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);

            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-requested-with, Content-Type");

            String body = requestWrapper.getNewRequest();
            String header = requestWrapper.getHeader();
            if (body != null && header != null) {
                /*
                * Note:- This below line's first update the request and conver the imp's to imp by getting
                * the single first index object. if the object is not their this will not process ad send the simple same
                * json string for validation if the string valid then dofilter map the json into @Pojo.
                * */
                log.info("New:- "+"header " + header + ", body " + body);
                if (validatorService.isResponseValidator(body, InputType.REQUEST.toString().equals("REQUEST") ? InputType.REQUEST : null)) {
                    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, servletResponse);
                } else {
                    /*
                    * Note:- IF Validator fail this will show error
                    * if imp's size 0 then here
                    * if imp's object not their then here
                    * */
                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                    String responseMessage = "{\"result\": \"Oops an error happened!\nSomething bad happened uh-oh!\"}";
                    response.getWriter().print(responseMessage);
                }
            }
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            log.error("--Error--> "+ e.getMessage());
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

        }finally {
            long result = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
            log.info("Total response time -> (" + (result) + ") miliseconds");
            log.info("=================Request-End=====================");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

}


public class ReadHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Cross.class);

    private String body = "";
    private String newBody = "";
    private String header = "";
    private final String IMP = "imp";

    public ReadHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader();
        String line;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuffer.append(line);
        }
        setBody(stringBuffer.toString());
        // fetch header
        this.setHeader(request.getHeader("x-openrtb-version"));
        log.info("Old:- "+"header " + getHeader() + ", body " + getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream =
                new ByteArrayInputStream(getNewRequest().getBytes());
        return new ServletInputStream() {
            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                return byteArrayInputStream.read();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() { return false; }
            @Override
            public boolean isReady() { return false; }
            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener listener) {}

        };
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        log.info("Body-set");
        this.body = body;
        // set the new body also
        setNewRequest(getUpdateRequestBody(getBody()));
    }
    public void setHeader(String header) {
        log.info("Header-set");
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        log.info("Body-get");
        return this.body;
    }
    public String getHeader() {
        log.info("Header-get");
        return this.header;
    }

    private String getUpdateRequestBody(String body) {

        JSONObject jsonRequest = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(body);
        /**
         * Find the imp's list and convert into the json-object then add into the request as update's
         * */
        if(jsonRequest.get(IMP) != null) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRequest.getJSONArray(IMP);
            if(jsonArray != null && (jsonArray.isArray() && jsonArray.size() > 0)) {
                JSONObject impObject = jsonRequest.getJSONArray(IMP).getJSONObject(0);
                // remove the list of imp
                jsonRequest.remove(IMP);
                // add the new one into the json reqeust
                jsonRequest.put(IMP, impObject);
            }
        }
        return jsonRequest.toString();
    }

    private void setNewRequest(String body) {
        log.info("newBody set");
        this.newBody = body;
    }

    public String getNewRequest() {
        log.info("newBody get");
        return this.newBody;
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the source code for this example.https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/eventfire